# $f: X \to Y$ is $\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{B}$-measurable if and only if $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $B \in \delta$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ measurable space. A function $f: X \to Y$ is $\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{B}$-measurable if $f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{A}$ for all $B\in \mathcal{B}$

Suppose that $\delta \subset \mathcal{P}(Y)$ fulfills that $\sigma(\delta)=\mathcal{B}$.

$\sigma(\delta)$ is the sigma algebra generated by $\delta$

Proof that:

$f: X \to Y$ is $\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{B}$-measurable if and only if $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $B \in \delta$

Let $B\in \delta$ given that $\delta \subset \sigma (\delta)=\mathcal{B}$ then $B\in \mathcal{B} $, as $ f: X \to Y$ is $\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{B}$ measurable then $f^{- 1}(B)\in \mathcal{A}$.

For the other implication, I set a $B \in \mathcal{B}$ I should show that $f^{- 1}(B) \in \mathcal {A}$ but my working hypothesis only solves the problem for me when $B\in \delta$, how can I resolve this implication?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear (-1 for an unclear question)... which implication are you talking about ?. I guess that you want to prove that if $f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal A$ for all $B\in \delta $, then $f$ is measurable, right ? If yes, prove that $\{B\in \mathcal P(Y)\mid f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal A\}$ is a $\sigma -$algebra that contains $\delta $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is $\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{B}$ measurable. Then clearly, we see that if $B \in \delta$, we have $B \in \sigma(\delta) = \mathcal{B}$. Then $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{A}$.

Now suppose that for all $B \in \delta$, $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{A}$. Define $\Sigma = \{C \subseteq Y | f^{-1}(C) \in \mathcal{A}\}$. It is easy to verify that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $B$. And we see that $\delta \subseteq \Sigma$. Therefore, $\mathcal{B} = \sigma(\delta) \subseteq \Sigma$. That is, for $B \in \mathcal{B}$, $f^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{A}$. Then $f$ is measurable.